# using std::string_view_literals::operator""sv produces warning in MSVC: Is this warning correct?

Tags: c++

Following code:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

using std::string_view_literals::operator""sv;

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello"sv << '\n';
}
```

Causes warning in MSVC: `warning C4455: 'operator ""sv': literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved.`

But no warnings in GCC and CLANG - check [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/6rMrhsGe4).

Considering `sv` is "known" reserved operator, is MSVC behavior incorrect?

Comment: This is the known issue since at least 2015 https://studiofreya.com/2015/01/18/c4455-operator-w-literal-suffix-identifiers-that-do-not-start-with-an-underscore-are-reserved/ and 2018 https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-c4455-issued-when-using-standardized-liter/270349 It can be suppressed by `using namespace std::string_view_literals;`.